# log file not available when running batch file in task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can i make my Server to create Log File with my batch file that run with Task Scheduler? I already created batch file with script :

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\robocopy.exe" "\\server1\e$\User Files" "\\server2\g$\User Files" /MIR /B /R:0 /W:0 /LOG:userfiles.txt /NFL /NDL`

when I run it manually, it does create log file.

Please help me...

Comment: windows 2008 server r2

Comment: running as an administrator

Comment: Firstly you dont need to give the full path of `Robocopy` it is in the system path already and for the log file try giving it a path to save to. EG: `/LOG:\\server2\g$\User Files\userfiles.txt` it is likly that the text file is being save to whatever the current directory is.